# Executing sys.xp_readerrorlog with OPENROWSET

Tags: sql, t-sql, permissions, sql-server-2008-r2, openrowset

The following runs successfully:

```
EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog 0
```

This however does not:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'SQLNCLI', 
    'Server=.;Trusted_Connection=Yes;',
    'EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog 0')
```

I am logged in using my Windows account and I have `sysadmin` permissions on all databases on my local server, including the system databases.

Here is the error message:

> Msg 7357, Level 16, State 2, Line 11
>   Cannot process the object "EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog 0". The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked
>   server "(null)" indicates that either the object has no columns or the
>   current user does not have permissions on that object.

I've checked the folder permissions on **`C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData`** just in case that it was an issue with `OPENROWSET` creating a temp file but local administrators (I'm in the group) have full control.

Why am I getting this error and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'SQLNCLI', 
    'Server=.;Trusted_Connection=Yes;',
    'SET FMTONLY OFF;EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog 0')
```

Basically, it's trying to infer the shape of the result before running the procedure.

> Using that set option means the only way this will be possible is by executing the procedure.